# LSTM keras, music MIDI generation, output converges to a fixed configuration

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, midi

I have a project on Neural Networks on music using MIDI files as inputs.
I'm thinking of a NN composed by 2 LSTM layers, followed by a dense one.

My data is organized in arrays (matrix with shape = [length, 128] - representing the MIDI files).
In the MIDI array, each row - a 128 elements array - represents an "instant", i.e. what notes are being played at each instant, with the corresponding velocity.

Now, what I know about lstm is the theory behind it, but - in practice - I know almost nothing.

My idea was to train an LSTM-NN using random "windows" of 256 rows input, to predict the following 1.
In this way, the network should learn how to map a serie of 256 "insants" to the following 1.

[image]

[image]

[GENERATION]

Given that, the network should then try to start from a 256 instants window (taken from an existing song) and try to produce 1 following instants, then, taking the old 255 instants + the predicted 1, try to produce other 1 instants and so on... In this way I should have a "new" song, starting from 256 instants taken from a song.

[PROBLEM]

This brings the prediction to converge to a fixed result, so my result is a song that starts with the 256 "cool" instants, then - after few instants - is a constant vector representing some notes that are played forever. Like someone standing on a piano for 2 minutes.

This problem makes me think that there is something wrong with the model.

Given what I described before, is my model correct?

[MODEL]

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer((num_steps,ENCODING)))
model.add(keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(hidden_size2, return_sequences=False))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(hidden_size3,activation="relu"))
if use_dropout:
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(ENCODING, activation=mapping_to_target_range))
```

This is my model, which uses these parameters:

[PARAMETERS]

```
num_steps = 256
prediction_steps = 12
train_batch_size = 32
val_batch_size = 1
hidden_size = 512
hidden_size2 = 256
hidden_size3 = 128
use_dropout = True
num_epochs = 10
data_path = "checkpoints"
ENCODING = 128
TIME_STEPS_PER_SONG = 500
```

This is my model.summary()
[SUMMARY]

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
cu_dnnlstm_1 (CuDNNLSTM)     (None, 256, 512)          1314816   
_________________________________________________________________
cu_dnnlstm_2 (CuDNNLSTM)     (None, 256)               788480    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               32896     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 128)               16512     
=================================================================
Total params: 2,152,704
Trainable params: 2,152,704
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And this is my generator
[GENERATOR]

```
def generate(data, num_steps,prediction_steps, batch_size):
    size = len(data)
    while True:
        x = []
        y = []

        for i in range(batch_size): 
            j = np.random.randint(size)
            song = np.array(data[j])
            start = np.random.randint(0,len(song) - num_steps - prediction_steps )
            x.append(song[start:start + num_steps])
            y.append(song[(start + num_steps + 1)])
            j += 1
        yield np.array(x, dtype=np.float32), np.array(y ,dtype=np.float32)

def mapping_to_target_range( x, target_min=0, target_max=127 ) :
    # x in range(0,1)
    return keras.backend.clip(x,0,127)
```

[TRAIN]

```
model.fit_generator(generate(data,num_steps,prediction_steps,train_batch_size), TIME_STEPS_PER_SONG, num_epochs,
                 validation_data=generate(data,num_steps,prediction_steps,val_batch_size),
                    validation_steps=1, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

[TRAINING ERROR]

The training error is something around a hundred, the strange thing is that it doesn't really seem to follow a trend (epoch by epoch), it bounces between 150 and 100, the val_loss instead seems to decrease, but it is around 50 and 20... It doesn't make much sense

Is this correct for my purpose? 
Do you know what could be wrong?

Is there something wrong with the model structure, or the training samples?

[IMPORTANT EDIT]
I changed encoding for the input, I used a vector of 129 elements, the last column represents the "time this configuration will be the same".
So for example, if I play "C2" and, after 50 "ticks", I play also "C4"; I'll have 2 vector, one representing C2, the following one representing both C2 and C4. 
The first vector will have as last column the value 50, the second one will have the time to reach the following event.

This configuration should avoid to train on something which prediction will be - highly probable - the last "instant" played. This happens maybe because it is highly improbable to find the instant in which a change in notes happens!

Given this new configuration, the net generates a series of zeroes with the last column (representing the time that configuration keeps playing) that increases each generation (?)

e.g.
[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 36]]

[GENERATION CODE]

```
model.load_weights("checkpoints/model-09.hdf5")
data = np.load("datasets_raw/Hou01.npy")
batt = np.array(data[:num_steps,:])
num_ticks = len(data)
generated_song = []
for tick in np.array(batt):
    generated_song.append(tick)
i = 0
while len(generated_song) < 2000:

    song = np.array(generated_song)
    batt = np.array([song[i:i+num_steps]])
    new_tick = model.predict(batt)
    tick = np.array(new_tick,dtype=np.uint8)
    generated_song.append(tick[0])
    print(tick)
    i += 1
```

Comment: How are you training this model?

Comment: @DanielMöller thanks for the questions I'll edit the post

Comment: Are you getting good results in training?

Comment: @DanielMöller i'll edit with a screenshot

Comment: This looks like a complicated issue that depends on the shape of your solution space and the nature of the data. Can you explain why do you expect this algorithm not to converge? For example, I can imagine (although I'm not a LSTM expect, so sorry if this doesn't make sense) that most of your songs are in some particular key, so some chords are used more often than others, which makes the model predict this chord/note more and more often with each generation.

Comment: I thought of something like this:
Given that when training, the net receives some random chain of 256 notes and tries to predict the following one, is highly improbable that the predicted value should be different from the previous one. This means that - maybe - the net learns something like "the last note will be the prediction", this leads to the problem that when generating, by applying this criteria to a chain of 256 notes, it generates the last note forever, with maybe some light difference, but after some iterations the generated note will be always the same!

Comment: I'll type an edit to show what I changed and what has changed in generation!

Comment: @DanielMöller ok now - I don't really know why - it produces something with more sense, it just has the "velocity" too low to be heard, but making all notes different from 0, equal to 80 it produces a song! Just an horrible song, but it is somehow producing sounds! Ahah 

Thanks a lot for the help! It was really useful to think of my errors! I need for sure to keep working on this project, but thanks!

Comment: Something that might make it easier with velocity is to keep it in range from 0 to 1 and use a final activation = 'simoid'. I believe you're not expecting that your song would necessarily reach 127 or 0, right? (Do you have a note for silence?)

Comment: @DanielMöller actually 0 means "no sound", so when the event "note_off" comes in, the velocity will turn to 0. But thanks for the advice! I can first normalize the velocity, then after producing a song I can de-normalize to a range 0..127! I'll let you know the results! 

[little edit]
With some modifications I obtained some sort of song ahhaha now I'm trying to train on a different dataset and overfit. I'll let you know ;)